# Difference between setExtremes and afterSetExtremes in HighStock

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am a newbie to Highchart and I have a question about `setExtremes` and `afterSetExtremes`, I am not sure I understand the difference between them.

Here is a senario:
There is a function that retrieve json data from server in `setExtremes` call back function. I will pre-set a chart range using `setExtremes` (say 2015-01-01 to 2015-05-01) and so that every time once I set the chart range, this function will be called to get new data from server, but the data got from server may has a different date range (say 2015-03-01 to 2015-05-04). I would like to adjust the chart range according to the new ranges from data. But if I use `setExtremes`  again in the `setExtremes` call back function, an infinite loop will occur.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes says

> this event fires after the final min and max values are computed

So I imagine this would solve my problem, but I am not sure how exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Difference is as described in API reference: `setExtremes` can be called with unacceptable range - in `afterSetExtremes` ranges are corrected.

You could extend Highcharts to alter min and max before values will be send to original `setExtremes` function. Lazy loading demo of Highcharts uses dynamic loading of data, so lets add wrapper to that jsFiddle.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yu6ztw7h/

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'setExtremes', function (proceed) {
        var newMin = arguments[1],
            newMax = arguments[2];

        arguments[1] = (newMin+newMax)/2;

        // Run original proceed method
        proceed.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

In this case start of range (newMin) will be changed to half of original range. You could load data in wrapper, check its extremes, pass changed values to original method.